# Remove duplicated items from array-object that is inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to remove duplicated items from an array object that is a property inside another array.

I don't want to remove all duplicates but leave only one unique.

I have this array:

```
const arr = [
  {
    foo: "test",
    bar: [
      {
        address: "Duplicated",
        port: 100001,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    foo: "Test2",
    bar: [
      {
        address: "Duplicated",
        port: 100000,
      } /*Remove this duplicate in every property bar but only by the property `address` */,
      {
        address: "Not duplicated",
        port: 100000,
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

The output would be something like this:

```
[
  {
    foo: "test",
    bar: [
      {
        address: "Duplicated",
        port: 100001,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    foo: "Test2",
    bar: [
      {
        address: "Not duplicated",
        port: 100000,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I tried several things but all got me nowhere, I'm very confused with this.

Comment: Please include code that you have tried. You'll get feedback on what you're actually missing instead of just code that works for this one case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    foo: "test",
    bar: [
      { address: "Duplicated", port: 100000 }
    ]
  },
  {
    foo: "Test2",
    bar: [
      { address: "Duplicated", port: 100000 },
      { address: "Not duplicated", port: 100000 }
    ]
  }
];

// initialize empty Set
const addressSet = new Set();
// iterate over arr
const res = arr.map(item => {
  const current = {...item};
  // filter current item's bar list
  current.bar = current.bar.filter(({ address }) => 
    // if address is in set remove it from arr, otherwise add it to the set
    addressSet.has(address) 
      ? false 
      : addressSet.add(address)
  );
  return current;
});

console.log(res);
```